# Enable cURL in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl

I am trying to enable curl in the .htaccess file.

The reason for this is this error I got:

```
Warning: curl_exec() has been disabled for security reasons in [PATH] on line [LINE]
```

And i don't have access to the php.ini file (I use shared hosting).
My host says that I can enable curl using .htaccess but I have no clue how.

I have absolutely no experience with .htaccess so keep that in mind.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would someone disable it, when you can easily enable it afterwards. I mean, you cannot.

Comment: add `php_extension libcurl.so`
 or
`php_extension curl.so`

Comment: @Dagon As you can see from the error message, PHP is aware of the curl extension but cannot execute the function curl_exec()

Comment: You might still be able to have `php.ini`-overrides. Check your `phpinfo()` result. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688944/overriding-php-ini-in-a-shared-development-environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use phpinfo() function to see `disable_functions` parameter.

<strike>Then you can enable it removing it from list with this line of `.htaccess`:</strike>

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value disable_functions "all of them without curl_exec"
</IfModule>
```

Further reading: http://php.net/configuration.changes

#### Edit: This is not possible outside of php.ini

As seen in http://php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions -> disable_functions (php.ini only).

> **disable_functions** (string)
>
> > This directive allows you to disable certain
> >     functions for security reasons. It takes on a comma-delimited list of
> >     function names. disable_functions is not affected by Safe Mode.
> >
> > Only internal functions can be disabled using this directive.
> >     User-defined functions are unaffected.
> >
> > **This directive must be set in php.ini For example, you cannot set this
> >     in httpd.conf.**

Talk your web hosting provider about this problem.

Best regards,

Answer (score 4):

To be able to change any option through .htaccess at all, your server  administrator needs to configure your virtual host with

```
AllowOverride Options
```

Options passed with `php_admin_value` cannot be overwriten in .htaccess at all.

Not all options can be changed during any stage, `disable_functions` can **only** be overwritten in `php.ini` (see http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php), not in .htaccess.

So you have **no chance to enable curl**.
Maybe talking to your hoster helps.

Answer (score -2):

This might work, but it might be nice to see what other functions have been disabled for security reasons.

In .htaccess:

```
php_admin_value disable_functions " "
```